# How do I debug an error of a switch case that is being called out from a function file?

Tags: matlab, function, switch-statement

I have this code, when I try to run it, the following messages appear:

```
Error in LoadFunctionCP (line 20)
switch type

Error in TEST2 (line 34)
        p=amp*LoadFunctionCP(x,L,type); %compute p at current
        value of x
```

The LoadFunctionCP is in another file and I'm calling it from "MY CODE" file. At first it was saying there were too many output arguments and was able to fix that, but now those messages appear and I have no idea how to fix it. I believe the second error is because of the first error since there's something wrong with the 'type'. The type # is being input in 'MY CODE' I've been trying to debug it but I've had no luck. Could you guys help me?

Thank you

````
    %%%%%% FUNCTION FILE  %%%%%%%%%%%

            function [p] = LoadFunctionCP(x,L,type)

              clc;clear;

              switch type

              case 1 % Constant load 
              p = 1;

              case 2 % Linear ramp up
              p = x/L;

              case 3 % Linear ramp down
              p = 1 - x/L;

              case 4 %sinusoid distribution
              p = sin(pi*x/L);

            end


    ```

     %%%%%%%%% MY CODE %%%%%%%%

            clear; clc;


            %physical properties
            L=10; %length of entire bar
            EA=100; %EA set to 100

            %parameters
            nsimp=21; %number of simpson points
            GTR=51; %number of GTR points
            BETA=.5; %Beta(GTR parameter)
            dx= L/(GTR-1);


            %end conditions

            fixed=[1,0]; %boundary conditions
            free=[0,1]; %boundary conditions
            BC=[fixed,fixed]; %boundary conditions
            type=4; %half sinusoid
            amp=3; %amplitude

            %%%%%%%%%
            %Simpsons Rule
            wt = repmat([4,2],1,nsimp);%repeats the numbers in the [],how many rows, how many columns
            wt=[1,wt,4,1]; %Establish Simpson weight
            npts=length(wt); %number of Simpson points
            h=L/(npts-1); %step size between points
            wt=wt*h/3; %complete the Simpson wts
            Int=0; %initializing integral to zero
            Int1=0;

            for i=1:npts %loop over simpson points
               x=L*(i-1)/(npts-1);
               p=amp*LoadFunctionCP(x,L,type); %compute p at current value of x
               Int=Int+wt(i)*p; %integrals for I0
               Int1=Int1*(1/EA)*wt(i)*(L-x)*p; %Integrals for I1
            end

            %computation for simpson's rule
            d=L/EA;
            z=[Int;Int1]; %copmute z by Simpson's rule
            B=[1 0 -1 0;d 1 0 -1]; %(4x1) array, '1' when unknown and '0' when known
            C=B(:,BC==1); %take all rows and any column that is 1 in the array BC
            s=C\z; %reduced system, solve system for 2 unknowns

            %%%%%%%%%%%%%

            %trapezoidal rule integer
            f=[0;0;0;0]; %setting up the array
            f(BC==1)=s;


            Nold=f(1); %setting N to the first array

            Uold=f(2); %setting U to the second array
            x=0;
            History=zeros(GTR,4);

       %for loop
       for i=1:GTR;
       Pold=amp*LoadFunctionCP(x,L,type);
       History(i,:)=[x,Nold,Pold,Uold];
       x=x+dx;
       pnew=amp*LoadFunctionCP(x,L,type);
       Nnew=Nold-dx*(BETA*Pold+(1-BETA)*pnew);
       Unew=Uold+dx/EA*(BETA*Nold+(1-BETA)*Nnew);
       Nold=Nnew;
       Uold=Unew;
       end

       %display of graphs
       figure(1); hold on; grid on; %figure1 is 'Axial Force' with xlabel of 'x' and ylabel of 'N'
       xlabel('X'); ylabel('N');
       title('Axial Force');

       plot(History(:,1),History(:,2));
       hold off;

       figure(2); hold on; grid on; %figure2 is 'load' with xlabel of 'x' and ylabel of 'P'
       xlabel('X'); ylabel('P');
       title('Load');

       plot(History(:,1),History(:,3));
       hold off;

       figure(3); hold on; grid on; %figure2 is 'Displacement' with xlabel of 'x' and ylabel of 'U'
       xlabel('X'); ylabel('U');
       title('Displacement');

       plot(History(:,1),History(:,4));
       hold off;
````

Comment: I spotted the issue quickly. But for next time, please first read [mre]. The code you posted is much, much longer than necessary to reproduce the problem. Creating the minimal example that reproduces the bug will often help you find the problem yourself. If not, it will be a lot easier for someone else to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `clear` at the top of the function. This clears all variables, including `type`. The next statement, `switch type` is thus calling the function `type` (the variable that was shadowing the function doesn’t exist any more). `type` doesn’t return any values, so `switch` has no input to switch on.